# Best way to "label" a search field with several search options

Tags: html, forms

I have a search form, and am a little confused. I have 4 options that people can choose from, which sit right above the SearchQueryTextBox, and I'm not sure what to make of them...

Should they be a `label`, a `legend`, or an `a`?

I don't think they should be a `legend`.

I was thinking that I should make them all `label`s, since it makes the most sense semantically.

Here's what I'm talking about:

[image]

[Edit]: Each 'option' above the textbox is clickable. e.g. if a user clicks Accessories, then the textbox will gain focus and allow them to search for Accessories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they're clickable they should be `button`'s or `a`'s

Are you just after the most semantic markup, or do you want this to make sense for javascript disabled etc.?

Comment: Well, one of the requirements is that the user have javascript enabled, otherwise they won't have the same experience (which happens to be the entire point of this particular website), so I'm not worried at all about whether or not javascript is disabled. So I guess just semantic markup.

Comment: If you assume Javascript, you can set a hidden input's value whenever the respective `a` is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that since they're options, you should use `<select>` and `<option>`. This also allows for graceful degradation; without javascript, it becomes a form.

Comment: yeah, that makes good sense. Say, would there be anything wrong with having, say 4 `label` tags?

Comment: I totally forgot about that. Yeah, can't use `label`s. I probably will use `select` with `option` but I'm just not sure how I can style them so they look the way they do in the pic above. I mean, how do you turn a dropdown box into 4 separate horizontally-placed "links"?

Comment: I think CSS is powerful enough. Let me see if I can get something working.

Comment: Oh, that would be awesome. :-)

Comment: I can't get anything going. Apparently `select` elements are notoriously hard to style.

Comment: no worries, thanks for your help, and for trying to help with the styling.